# Minikube : watch for code changes in locally mounted folder

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm mounting a local folder into minikube and using that folder inside a pod. The folder contains the code I am developing. It works great but changes I make are not being reflected in the browser. If I exec into the pod I can see my code changes, just not in the browser.

If I delete the pod when it is automatically recreated the changes are reflected in the browser. Is this a limitation of the solution?

Can anybody please advise a novice?

Comment: [this is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42635183/225016) but: _I make are not being reflected in the browser. If I exec into the pod I can see my code changes, just not in the browser._

That sounds like an application problem, especially given that you see the code changes when you exec into the Pod. What application are you running that you would expect to notice the change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kubernetes Minikube hostPath mount not reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591367/kubernetes-minikube-hostpath-mount-not-reloading)

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but I've gotten good mileage out of developing applications purely locally and using good local debugging tools; _then_ building a Docker container, and only _then_ deploying to Kubernetes.  You don't actually want to deal with file sync issues between your development environment, the minikube VM, and the Docker filesystem inside of that (each of which has their own filesystem).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Skaffold](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/) — and its [`sync`](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/blob/master/examples/annotated-skaffold.yaml); it ensures your yaml files are running inside Minikube and ships files of your selection back and forth.